# PHP function/library to create screenshot from movie

Tags: php, javascript, screenshot, movie

I have a site where users upload movies (MP4, FLV, OGV).

I need a PHP function to generate a poster/screenshot in JPG automatically from an uploaded movie. The screenshot should be for the opening scene of the movie.

If it is a javascript utility (rather than PHP), that will be fine too.

I can't find anything. Where should I look?

Comment: JavaScript is not capable of screen capture for a video source.

Comment: @Diodeus actually, it is. google "javascript video processing".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org). It's a very capable video manipulation tool that can be run from PHP with [`exec()`](http://php.net/exec). For example, to extract the first frame from a video file, you could use:

```
ffmpeg -i video.flv -ss 0 -vframes 1 shot.png
```

Comment: i did some benchmark, and for me mplayer works 100 times faster than ffmpeg, in special if you jump to a specific time

Answer (score 3):

You could easily do that with [ffmpeg-php](https://github.com/char0n/ffmpeg-php).  You will need to have FFMPEG installed on the server for this.