# How install ffmpeg on wamp server (windows 7 - x64)

Tags: php, ffmpeg, wampserver

Please take a look at all these depricated links :
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Install+ffmpeg+in+windows

i installed wamp server on my **windows 7 (x64)** machine and want to install ffmpeg on it.

here is my wamp server version :
**wampserver2.5-Apache-2.4.9-Mysql-5.6.17-php5.5.12-64b**

[image: wampserver2.5-Apache-2.4.9-Mysql-5.6.17-php5.5.12-64b]

here is the official web site of ffmpeg :
http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/

i am really confused where can i download ffmpeg extension for php5.5.12 and how install it?
in their official web site there is only one link for download :
http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg-php/

and those downloaded files need perl to run and there is no **dll** files inside them.
would be really appreciate to help me step by step to install ffmpeg in my wamp server.

Comment: here is some download links with no dll file to install : http://ffmpeg.org/download.html | http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/ | https://github.com/CodeScaleInc/ffmpeg-php

Comment: Another related link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801573/php-function-library-to-create-screenshot-from-movie

Comment: Another related link : http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=5947

Comment: Another related link : http://myownhomeserver.com/2012/02/how-to-install-ffmpeg-php-for-windows-apache-http-server/

Comment: If you must run Windows, consider running FFMpeg in a virtual machine on the server, e.g. using Vagrant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original `ffmpeg-php` extension was released for Linux. There were some Windows builds at some point but the project is now deprecated and you'll have a hard time finding one. Besides, you'll be stuck with outdated libs.

Take a look at some of the new object-oriented FFmpeg wrappers like [PHP-FFmpeg](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg). It only needs the FFmpeg executables and you can use the [Zeranoe](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) Windows builds to install them easily.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but would you please explain more how can i install from this link : http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

Comment: You download the static build and extract it somewhere on your system. The executables are in the `bin` folder. You can then either the `bin` folder to the system **PATH** or specify the full path to them when you load the PHP-FFmpeg class.

Comment: thanks man, i also found this link : http://www.wikihow.com/Install-FFmpeg-on-Windows

Comment: Related link : How install using with Composer -> http://www.dev-metal.com/composer-tutorial/